# php file content is not correct for first time

Tags: php, laravel

I know it is a little unusual but it maybe happen for other guys then if you faced this issue please help me.
I write code under Laravel to download some files from a site.
almost the downloaded files are correct(name and content), but sometimes the name is correct but the content is not and if I download the file again it goes correct(name and content).i put my code here to help you to understand my issues
also, I use Cloudflare and ubuntu as my server OS

**Controller Code:-**

```
public function subDownload($id, $idSub)
{
    $my = MyAnimeListSub::scopes('active')->findOrFail($idSub);

    return $my->downloadFile();
}
```

**Class Model: MyAnimeListSub**

```
public function downloadFile()
{
    $path = Storage::subMyAnimeList()->path($this->file);

    Post::make()->download($this);

    return response()->download($path, $this->original_name);
}
```

**Class: Storage**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage as StorageMain;

public static function subMyAnimeList()
{
    return StorageMain::disk('myanimelist_sub');
}
```

**class: Post**

```
public function download($model)
    {
        $id = $model->id;

        $key = 'download_' . $model->getTable();

        $ids = array_values(explode('.', Cookie::get($key)));

        if (in_array($id, $ids)) {
            return;
        }

        $ids[] = $id;

        Cookie::queue($key, implode('.', $ids), 60 * 24 * 30);

        $model->increment('download');
    }
```